# Writing a mathematical statement: $n$ is a natural number bigger or equal to two

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

I want to know how to write: '$n$ is a natural number bigger or equal to two' in mathematical terms. My thoughts:

- $$n\in\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0,1\}\tag1$$
- $$n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge2}\tag2$$
- $$ n\in\mathbb{N}\space\wedge\space n\ge2\tag3$$

Which one is the best? Or am I wrong about this.

Comment: "$n\geq 2$ is a natural number."

Comment: Words are underrated

Comment: @RobArthan True, I edited my question.

Comment: There is no right answer. If you are going to be talking about such numbers a lot, then it is probably worthwhile introducing and explaining a notation like $\Bbb{N}_{\le2}$ as in your (2). Some people won't like the use of mathematical logic symbols as in $(3)$, but it's fine if you are working in mathematical logic. Likewise some people will prefer words to the set operations as in your (1), but again, that's fine if you are working with lots of different subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ and using set operations to describe them.

Comment: My inclination is to write "$2\le n\in\mathbb{N}$."

Comment: @BarryCipra does the inequality sign need to be flipped?

Comment: @JanE, why would it need to be flipped? You want $2$ to be *less* than or equal to $n$, right?

Comment: An alternative would be to do it with $n\gt 1$  (sometimes $\ge$ is a derived idea, where $\gt$ is defined as a primitive concept). But only if such pedantry matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "$n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge2$" would be the best compromise, maybe also "$n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge2$", which can be abbreviated as "$n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n\ge2$"

Answer (score 3):

Writing mathematically an expression doesn't mean you have to use only symbols. Often, for clarity is better to combine symbols and words.

Also writing with only symbols tends to be more prone error.

It's better to say

"Any non-empty subset of natural numbers has a minimum"

or

"For any $A \subseteq \mathbb N$, if $A\ne\emptyset$ then there exists a minimum element $a\in A$"

that

$\forall A (A\subseteq \mathbb N \,\wedge A\ne\emptyset \implies \exists a(a\in A\, \wedge\forall b(b\in A \implies a\le b)))$

For the specific statement you are asking i would use something like "Let $n\in \mathbb N, n\ge 2$".

Actually, often $n$ denotes a natural number, so, unless the context could lead to confusions, i would only write "Let $n\ge 2$".

Comment: Can’t agree more with this, especially in the third example.  I will never understand why people insist on writing things that way.